# Recursive increasing counting

Tags: python, recursion

Hello I am trying to learn basic recursive function on Python and I am doing some of few exercises for practice. I am trying to make a function that returns the number that increments of between numbers are less than k using recursive, but I have found the proper method but increasing the counts is problem here is my code so far...

```
testList = [(1), (6), (7), (9), (14)]
def count_test(loc_list, k):
    counts = 0
    if len(loc_list) == 1:
        return print(counts)
    else:
        if loc_list[1] - loc_list[0] < k:
            counts += 1
            del loc_list[0]
            count_test(loc_list,k)
        else:
            del loc_list[0]
            count_test(loc_list, k)
```

`count_test(testList, 3)`

I want to get 2 which are between 6 and 7, and 7 and 9 but the counts are not incrementing I think it is the problem that I put the "counts =0"
I know this is really stupid question, but I cannot find the solution. 
Please help me

Comment: `++counts`.....

Comment: Python doesn't have a `++` operator like some other languages do.  Use `counts += 1` instead

Comment: Please explain what you want the function to do more precisesly

Comment: @JoeIddon Hi I would like to get number of list that difference between elements and elements are less then k. So I have list and I would like to calculate difference one by one consecutively with previous one. And I would like to check if those calculations are less than k. so for that output, I would like to get 2 because between 6,7 and 7,9 differences are less than 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the problem is arising from the fact that each `function` creates its own `counts` `variable` set to `0`. What you want is to pass this value between `functions`. To do this, we could use a `global` (bad idea) or just pass it in as another `parameter`. If we use the `syntax` of `counts=0` in the `function` definition, then when calling it from the root node, we don't need to specify to start with `0` `counts`.

Oh, and also, `Python` does not support the `++` `syntax` seen in some other languages, instead you must use `counts += 1`.

```
def count_test(loc_list, k, counts=0):
    if len(loc_list) == 1:
        return print(counts)
    else:
        if loc_list[1] - loc_list[0] < k:
            counts += 1
            del loc_list[0]
            count_test(loc_list,k,counts)
        else:
            del loc_list[0]
            count_test(loc_list, k,counts)
```

and a test by calling:

```
count_test(testList, 3)
```

gives:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't include a ++ function like c and other languages do, you will have to use an alternative.

```
counts += 1 #Will add one every time
```

or

```
counts += counts #Adds value of counts to itself
```

Comment: Still I get 0. I think its because I put counts = 0, but I cannot think of way that I can put counts inside the function but does not call "counts = 0" every time it recursived.

Comment: Use `global counts = 0`

Comment: is there other way? that I can instance in the recursive function?